# После переустановки denwer не работает сайт

Tags: wordpress, denwer

Был рабочий сайт, работающий на локальном сервере denwer. Далее я переустановила denwer и папку с сайтом скопировала на рабочий стол. После переустановки denwer скопировала папку с сайтом на новый локальный сервер, создала базу с таким же названием, но вся информация с сайта пропала (плагины, страницы и т.д.). Подскажите, как можно исправить проблему.

Comment: А базу-то старую не сохранили что-ли?

Comment: Нет. Весь контент был на вордпрессе, остались все папки  с темами, плагинами. Я поняла, что я ошиблась

Comment: Денвер установила поверх старого, там был запрос, что-то вроде "у Вас есть сайт, данные не повредятся, но все-таки, Вы уверенны?" (денвер перестал работать, поэтому я его переустанавливала) Возможно, что база сохранилась?

Comment: Не знаю. Скорее всего, нет.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы всё сохранилось как и было, вам надо было дамп базы данных сделать перед переустановкой. Вся информация, которая присутствует на сайте WordPress хранится в БД, не в файлах!

И к тому же, если сайт перестал работать, то скорее всего эта ошибка была записана в вашу старую БД и даже если бы вы переустановили ВП и подключили старую БД к нему, то скорее всего ошибка осталась.

Совет на будущее - Перед каждой (ВНИМАНИЕ!), перед каждой правкой сохраняйте резервную копию и запоминайте что вы делаете. Чтобы можно было на крайней случай подключиться по FTP и вернуть назад то, что намутили.

Answer (score 0):

Когда уже перед переносом сайта народ научится пользоваться плагином Duplicator? База данных при переустановке определённо была снесена.